# Clearing table alternatives in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I want to clear a table but not sure which way is the best and does what different than each other. What are the differences among these:

```
tbl = {}
```

```
for k, v in pairs(tbl) do v = nil end
```

```
for k, v in pairs(tbl) do tbl[k] = nil end
```

Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't be bothered to write a proper answer, but shortly: the first creates a new table, keeping the original untouched (so if it's referenced from elsewhere, it will be still valid there); the second does nothing to the table (you're just assigning to the local variable); the third changes all values to `nil` so if the table is used elsewhere, it will be useless there after you do that. Now keep in mind that table keys and values may themselves be tables, and "nilling" those as well is an even bigger overkill than nilling jsut the table. Why do you need this? Some context wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Welp, I did not know _v_ is actually a local variable... Explains why some things did not work back then. Thank you. Well, you are saying nilling all the values in the table that may themselves be tables is an overkill, and instead, I should just nil the table itself, and then transform it to a table after that's done if I want it to end up being a table afterwards. Is this right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. What I'm saying is that if you want to completely "clear" the `tbl` table (for whichever reason), you may want to also consider recursively clearing the tables which `tbl` contains as keys and values. I cannot say what would be better because I don't know what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```lua
tbl = {}
```

This doesn't so much clear the table as just create a new one. The old one *might* get garbage-collected, depengin on whether there are other references to it.

```lua
for k, v in pairs(tbl) do v = nil end
```

This does absolutely nothing. It's a waste of processing power.

```lua
for k, v in pairs(tbl) do tbl[k] = nil end
```

This actually empties the table without creating a new one. For small tables, this is often more performant than creating a new table, as it means less work for the GC, but that's a somewhat advanced optimization technique and it's not like clearing tables is always better.

Note that `pairs` uses the [`next`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next) function, which can handle keys being removed while iterating.